# I am not able to get dictionary keys

Tags: python, json, request, abstract-syntax-tree

**I made an api request in which the content iconverted into dictionary but after nested key item all the other content were in string which I wanted to in dictionary to make it easy to find mint address so as it was in string I seperated that part and replaced all braces and the converted into dictionary using loop as traditional method of ast and json were not giving desired result but the end dictionary is showing an error when I am using .key() comannd that there is no key **

```
import requests
import convReq # this is private module i'll provide its code down below
import json
import ast
def user_details(nft_address):
    xurl='https://api.solscan.io/transfer/token?token_address='+nft_address+'&type=all&offset=0&limit=1'
    #return byte array
    datar=requests.get(xurl).content
    xy=convReq.convert_to_dict(datar)
    return xy

y=(user_details("EwESGGqNuPLdK4Q5yLAiTEtDJm15FrPFT3ZyoCRcDgpd"))
print(type(y))
x=json.dumps(y['data']['items'])
print(x)
print ("\n", type(x))

#print ("final string = ", x)

x=x.replace("[","").replace("]","").replace("{","").replace("}","").replace('"',"")
word=""
dict={}
wkey=""
for char in x:
    if char==":":
        wkey=word
        word=""
    elif char==",":
        dict[wkey]=word
        word=""
    else:
        word=word+char

print("--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
print(dict)
print(type(dict))
print(dict["mint"])


################################
#private code convReq part
import ast
from ast import literal_eval
import json
def convert_to_dict(xdata):
     xdata=str(xdata, 'UTF-8')
     xdata=json.loads(xdata)
     return(xdata)

def convert_to_json(my_byte):
    my_json=my_byte.decode('utf8').replace("'",'"')
    datax=json.loads(my_json)
    s=json.dumps(datax,indent=4,sort_keys=True)
    return s
```

Comment: What does the output look like? Also, take a look at the code you've posted and make sure you haven't posted any API keys.

Answer (score 0):

You code is correct, but you are not considering the `whitespaces` in the string, that is causing you problems.

Instead of `mint` as key, the dictionary was storing  `mint` as key. that's where key not found comes into picture.

Adding the below `replace(' ', "")` fixes the problem.

```py
x = x.replace("[", "").replace("]", "").replace(
    "{", "").replace("}", "").replace('"', "").replace(' ', "")
```

Answer (score 0):

In the above question, I made a major mistake as I was new to web scraping. This issue is due to a protocol known as cors which is used as a security measure to insure that the requests are made through the original site page... So to over this small issue we pass headers with API requests whose syntax is like:

```
headers={
'Host': 'www.luisaviaroma.com',
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/.........',
'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
'DNT': '1',
'Connection': 'keep-alive',
'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'document',
'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'navigate',
'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'none',
'Sec-Fetch-User': '?1'
}
#now we have to pass it like this:
request.get("https://www.anywebsite.com",headers=headers)
```

we can get headers for any website API by the network in the inspector by using the edit and resend option where we can see raw headers like this image>>>

[image: Example of how raw headers look]